# How to use the PHP '<?=' shorttag correctly

Tags: php, php-shorttags

Now that `<?=` is always available in PHP 5.4+, and the old rumours of it being depreciated in PHP6 are disappearing, it seems it's completely safe to use this handy little shortcut.

My question is: What's the correct syntax?

I couldn't find any examples of it on the PHP website, and it's apparently impossible to search for `<?=` on Google.

My understanding is that it's a shortcut for `<?php echo`, but doesn't that mean you should write:

`<?= $string; ?>`

Rather than:

`<?= $string ?>`?

Or does it not make any difference because there's no more instructions after the initial `echo`?

Thanks.

Comment: documented: http://us2.php.net/echo (google **php "<?=" shortcut**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the PHP docs, you should use:

```
I have <?=$foo?> foo.
```

Source: https://www.php.net/echo

Comment: Also, for searching via Google you can try "php short open tag"

Comment: according to anyone who will have to maintain your code you should do `<?= $foo; ?>` for readability and consistency

Comment: @KaiQing why is that, exactly? In case of shorthand echo it doesn't improve either readability nor _grepability_ of the construct. I was always considered a _code beauty nazi_, but this one doesn't get to me.

Comment: Got to agree with @KaiQing that I find `<?= $foo; ?>` (or even `<?= $foo ?>`) more readable than the PHP docs example.

Comment: @Mateusz - You could argue that it is opinion either way. Im reciting rules of the firm and our network, as well as my own opinion. Not necessarily a global standard. If you feel it's ok and so does everyone that has to read the code then it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

Since `<?=` has always been a shorthand (prior to PHP 5.4 enabled/disabled using `short_open_tag`), it does not change language semantic. Therefore you are free to use either `<?= "hello" ?>` or `<?= "hello"; ?>`, just like with any other PHP one-liner.

It is a matter of style more than language construct, but whatever you choose, use it consistently throughout the project to ease further maintenance and readability.

Answer (score 1):

When you use  the last ; is optional, the same is true for the last ; of your php file

Answer (score 1):

After performing a bunch of simple tests, it appears that it doesn't really matter:

```
<?php echo 'hello' . "\n" ?>
<?php echo 'hello' . "\n"; ?>
<?= 'hello' . "\n" ?>
<?= 'hello' . "\n"; ?>
```

These all have the same output:
http://codepad.org/zWUUN9Sw